# Worst case big-Oh runtime analysis

Tags: big-o, time-complexity

I'm starting to learn about Big-Oh notation.

If I have for example:

```
int foo (int a[], int n) {  
   int x = 0, i, j;             // <-- c(0), 1 times
   for (i = 0; i < n; i++){     // <-- c(1), n times
      for (j = 0; j < i; j++)   // <-- c(2), n*n times?
          x += a[j];            // <-- c(3), 1 times
      }
      return x;
}
```

I understand that if the inner nested for-loop  was comparing j and n, then it would be O(n^2) overall. But since this j depends on the increment of i, it should execute x += a[j] proportional to i, but I'm not sure exactly how to express this in Big-Oh.

Comment: Conveniently there is currently a course running that has very good explanatory lectures https://www.coursera.org/course/algs4partI
Specifically Week 1: Analysis of Algorithms

Answer (score 1):

The outer loop `for (i = 0; i < n; i++)` runs exactly `n` times.

The inner loop `for (j = 0; j < i; j++)` runs exactly `i` times in each pass of the outer loop, and as you point out its different for each pass.

The total number of times we pass through the inner loop (and hence the statement `x += a[j];`) is thus the value of a series

```
0 + 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + (n - 1)
```

To write this in big-O notation, we need to estimate this sum.
This is a very common sum, in practice, you basically just memorize that the answer is `O(n^2)`, because you see it often.

To see it in detail you can use a trick invented by Gauss.
What makes the sum hard is that each entry has a slightly different value, so what you do is you try to pair off the elements, a big one with a small one, so that all the sums of the pairs have the same value.

```
(0) + (n-1) = n-1
(1) + (n-2) = n-1
(2) + (n-3) = n-1
...
(n/2 - 1) + (n - (n/2-1) - 1) = n - 1
```

Then you have `n/2` pairs whose sum is in each case `n-1`. So the overall sum `O(n^2)`, (and it is also `Omega(n^2)`, if you are also learning about that.)

You might ask about, what if `n` is odd, then there is one left over element. But it's contribution is only `O(n)`. And `O(n^2) + O(n)` is `O(n^2)`, in other words its contribution is negligible and we can ignore it.

So the overall complexity of the algorithm is indeed `O(n^2)`, and if for some reason you need to know the constant in the `O`, it's very nearly `n^2 / 2`.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is a function that iterates n*n times and executes one action - `x += ...`.

Now, each `x += ...` is done in constant time `O(1)`, so if it is done n*n times then you have a `O(N^2)`